# Is there anyway to target all of <th> in a table and declare same attribute for all of them?

Tags: html

I have this table with crazy amount of data and I was wondering if isn't there any way to access all `<th>`elements and set an `attribute` which will be applied to all of them?

For instance:

```html
<tr>
   <th colspan="7"> title </th>
</tr>
```

I just wanna declare them in the beginning so that I don't have to set each one of them, when I have a massive amount of data! :S

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, I'd recommend you put closer to your question by marking one of the answers as accepted. You can do so by clicking on a check mark by the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with HTML, but you can use jQuery and target all `th` like so:

```
$('th').attr('colspan', 7);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0tfxazow/

With pure JavaScript, you could write something like this:

```
let headings = document.querySelectorAll("th");
headings.forEach(function(heading) {
    heading.setAttribute("colspan", "3");
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0tfxazow/2/

Comment: Thank you!i was looking for something within HTML.guess,the scope is pretty low there without JS.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using jquery fairly easily. Im not sure there is anyway to do it dynamically with base HTML5 (besides copy and pasting that attribute).

```js
$("th").attr("colspan",7)
```

```css
tr,td,th {
    border: 2px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>
```